# Why does my installed app handle pkg_resources.iter_entry_points differently than in source?

Tags: python, setuptools, pkg-resources

I have a Python app that looks for plugins via `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points`.

When run directly from source checkout, this will find anything in `sys.path` that fits the bill, including source checkouts that happen to have an applicable `.egg-info` for `setuptools` to find.

Yet when I install the package anywhere via `python setup.py install`, it suddenly ceases to detect everything enumerated in `sys.path`, instead only finding things that are installed alongside it in `site-packages`.

- Why is `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points` behaving differently for the vanilla source checkout v. the installed application?
- How can I make it traverse everything in `sys.path`, as it does in development?

Comment: What distribution do you use? And which version?

Comment: @FelixYan OS X, Python 2.7.6, setuptools 2.2.1.

Comment: try see https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html and look for PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 2):

1. How to get it to iterate over sys.path?

   `pkg_resources.WorkingSet(None).iter_entry_points`
2. Why does it behave differently? Probably because the installed package forces at least the meta data about itself into memory. Looking at the code, my guess would be that your main module has a **requires** attribute, but that's only an educated guess. Anyway, to force the "installed" behaviour while developing, it should be enough to run `python setup.py develop`

Comment: Thank you! Using your answer I was able to monkey patch `pylibjpeg` like so: `pylibjpeg.utils.iter_entry_points = pkg_resources.WorkingSet(None).iter_entry_points`.

This allowed me to run this in a continuous kernel, which is a requirement for Kaggle Code competitions :)